# Where to share and demonstrate LWC code?

Tags: lwc-playground

The Playground in the Lightning component library gone, [WebComponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/create/lwc) redirecting  to [LWC.studio](https://app.lwc.studio/), the latter [announcing its shutdown](https://lwc.studio/404) at the beginning of 2024 - is there still a place to share and demo LWC code to everyone for free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (salesforce.com) recommended place to go today is StackBlitz. The free subscription tier includes unlimited projects and collections, browser-based IDE, ability to edit GitHub repos, 1MB file storage per project, and community support. However, it's not a standard template, so you have to [fork](https://stackblitz.com/fork/github/salesforce/lwc/tree/master/playground) from the [Salesforce LWC repo](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/tree/master/playground). I have personally bookmarked the first link so that I can quickly create a new LWC project whenever I need to.